# python file import from package

Tags: python, import, package

I have a python folder like this. How to import file1.py in  pkg2/file2.py

[image]

I tried to import like this in file2.py

`

```
from pkg1 import file1
```

`
But i got error like this

[image]

Could someone help me out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Answer (score 0):

If you set the PYTHONPATH environmental variable to the root folder, it should work, e.g on Windows:

```
set PYTHONPATH=. && python pkg2\file2.py
```